# How do you place two images together, with text, with both at center. I understand that you can change element size to make elements in center

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place two images side by side with their descriptions. Here is my code.

I intend to place two images side by side with their text. I tried to split div elements but the problem was that one piece of text was under the other, not next to the other. The text needs to be to the right of the image and the second image needs to be to the right of the first text.

```css
#sheets {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

#docs {
  width: 25%;
  margin: auto;
}

img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="sheets">
  <a href="Spreadsheet.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Flag_of_the_Roman_Empire.png" height="200" width="350"></a>
  <h1>Ancient Rome</h1>
  <p>Ancient Rome was a great civilization, that along with Ancient Greece, contributed to many things in the modern world, like architecture, numbers, letters, and government.</p>
</div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="docs">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Pantheon_Rom_1_cropped.jpg" height="125" width="125">
  <p>One famous building of Ancient Rome. It's in good condition because the building has been in active use since the 7th century. The Pantheon has a dome.</p>
</div>
<div id="docs">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Colosseum_in_Rome-April_2007-1-_copie_2B.jpg" height="125" width="125">
  <p>Another famous building. Was used for entertainment of huge crowds. Most people did not die in gladiator matches. The Colosseum has a lot of arches.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have a mistake in your html.  id's like "docs" need to be unique.  I changed that to a class.  Look into flexbox to arrange your images side by side.

```css
#sheets {
      width: 50%;
      margin: auto;
    }
    
    .docs {
      width: 25%;      
      
    }
    
    img {
      float: left;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    #container{
    display:flex;
    justify-Content:center;
    }
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="sheets">
    <a href="Spreadsheet.html"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Flag_of_the_Roman_Empire.png" height="200" width="350"></a>
    <h1>Ancient Rome</h1>
    <p>Ancient Rome was a great civilization, that along with Ancient Greece, contributed to many things in the modern world, like architecture, numbers, letters, and government.</p>
  </div><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
  <div id='container'>
  <div class="docs">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ef/Pantheon_Rom_1_cropped.jpg" height="125" width="125">
    <p>One famous building of Ancient Rome. It's in good condition because the building has been in active use since the 7th century. The Pantheon has a dome.</p>
  </div>
  <div class = "docs">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Colosseum_in_Rome-April_2007-1-_copie_2B.jpg" height="125" width="125">
    <p>Another famous building. Was used for entertainment of huge crowds. Most people did not die in gladiator matches. The Colosseum has a lot of arches.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```